# User data ingestion process from Google Tag Manager for Recommendation AI Google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, recommendation-engine, google-cloud-recommendation

Hi I have set up Recommendation AI with catalog data and user data.
User events are being fed from Google Tag Manager using 3 Recommendation AI tags.
1st Tag is for product page where I use ecommerce variable where I set up productid (this works as expected)
2nd Home page visit where I placed automl tag using custom html google tag with automl data with eventType: 'home-page-view' (this tag is just setting up the automl data layer) and second tag with Recommendation AI which is using automl data. (this doesn't work I don't see any other events than detailed-page-view in Recommender AI console)
[image]

As a side note I have added priority of firing tags to automl data layer 100 and the Recommendation AI left empty.

Anyone has any expirience with it?
To sum up I need to set up front-page-view and add-to-cart events but they are not being visible in Recommender AI just detailed-page-view

UPDATE
I'm still not able to receive the home-page-view event in the Recommendation AI using gtm.
I went extra mile and added new tag with custom html which creates automl variable in datalayer as per documentation (https://cloud.google.com/recommendations-ai/docs/user-events#tag-manager_10 - copy&paste from documentation):
[image]

The tag I have set up has 100 priority so it runs first.
Than there is a second tag for Recommedation AI where source of the data is set to AutoML (i have tried to override eventType variable with the Constant 'home-page-view' but it's not giving expected results either)
[image]

Running out of options here...

Comment: Have you checked Cloud Logging error logs? There may be some clues.

Comment: @kallusis369 thats the problem there are no traces there, just about unjoined events which is ok because it's below 0,04 percent

Answer (score 0):

Update:
The event_type override should work now for your tag.

Original:
The event_type override on gtm is allow list only - we would need to allow list your gtm tag for it to work (if you provide it I can enable for your tag). Alternatively, you think you could set the eventType directly in the data layer?

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for feedback as I stated above we are preparing automl format of data and ecommerce variable with eventType in it so we pretty much set it up.

Comment: I see. For the second tag, home-page-view, can you set the "event-type" directly in the automl layer as a workaround?

For the add-to-cart - my guess is the issue is related to trigger firing (e.g. data is not yet present in data layer when tag fires). Does your website have EE for add to cart events? You could also try just using EE on the page to get add to cart if present.

Comment: I have tried to set up automl tag, also in google tag manager in a preview everything is firing correctly so it's not the issue with data are not being yet available to the js.

Comment: Patrick please check my UPDATE if you have any suggestions I'm very curious what I can do more.

Comment: Hi Maciej, 


1) Did you check if the home page view is being sent via the network tab in your browser? Just curious if the issue is on the GTM side or on the Recommendations api side.


2) One other option to try - maybe change from "page view" to "window loaded" - the latter waits for the entire page to be loaded instead of as soon as the page is visited - maybe your data layer is not yet populated when the page view is triggered?

Comment: Also, do you mind trying the "event_type" override again? It should work now.

Comment: Hi Patrick thanks for your involvement to answer your question in tag manager debug I see the tag being fired but it actually not sending any POST request to https://recommendationengine.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/$PROJECT_ID/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/eventStores/default_event_store/userEvents:collect as on different pages. So GTM debugger shows me that the tag has been fired but there is no POST as an outcome of this action.

Comment: In this case, my guess is the data layer is not populated in time - so even if the tag is fired, it does not find the data in which case no data is sent. Did you try changing trigger to "window loaded"?